# Erase text from Edit Text using AndroidViewClient

Tags: python-2.7, view, androidviewclient

I am trying to automate a test case where i have to delete the data in EditText first , then enter new text and save it . i am using androidviewclient to find the views . 
enter code here
`Busy = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise('id/no_id/24')`
`Busy.touch()`
`vc.dump()`
`id16 = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise('id/no_id/16')`

id16 is the Edit Text , how to erase data in that view . please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the **View** is an **EditText** you can do:

```
id16 = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise('id/no_id/16')
for i in range(25):
    id16.backspace()
```

Comment: Can you please also let me know how to get the status of a radio button . my scenario is something like this : navigate to call barring , check if the service is enabled . navigation would be : Phone > Settings > GSM call settings > Call Barring > Outgoing barring > All calls . All calls has a radio button for which i have if the button is enabled or not . please help

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510146/how-can-i-get-the-status-of-check-box, if not enough just create a new question.

Comment: I have created a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138987/how-to-get-the-status-of-radio-button-using-androidviewclient   , please help

Answer (score 0):

for EditText containing some data you can do this:

```
view= vc.findViewById(ID)    
if view.getClass()=='android.widget.EditText':
    textPresent=view.getText()
    for i in range(len(textPresent)):
        view.backspace()
    print 'removed existing text'`
```

Though it deletes one character at a time and thus consumes lot of time for long strings